# Vue.js error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My knowledge of vue.js is limited but as far as i'm aware this should work, for some reason when I try to access my variable in the data property it can't find it.

[image]

```
data: function() {
    return {
        id: 0,
        clients: []
    }
},
methods: {
    getClientData(){
        fetch('/view-clients/' + this.id).then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (data) {
            this.clients = JSON.parse(data);
            this.id = this.clients[clients.length - 1].id;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo? Should be `this.clients[this.clients.length - 1].id`

Comment: Also, function scope applies here since you're not using arrow functions, so `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Even with the above comments applied, if it is expected to “work” not depends on the parsed result returned. However, insufficient information has been provided as to what this *really is*. That is, this questions does not represent a complete minimal reproduction.

Comment: Use arrow functions, otherwise `this` in your callbacks do not refer to the Vue component instance. Also, `clients` is undefined: do you mean `this.clients[this.clients.length - 1].id` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function scope is most likely the culprit. Use arrow functions instead so `this` refers to the Vue component.

```js
data() {
    return {
        id: 0,
        clients: []
    }
},
methods: {
    getClientData(){
        fetch('/view-clients/' + this.id).then((response) => response.text())
          .then((data) => {
            this.clients = JSON.parse(data);
            this.id = this.clients[this.clients.length - 1].id;
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
          });
    }
}
```